# Why does my previous state preserve despite using key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to reset my previous state when `filter_obj` changes.
Even though I reset page and itemData to 0 in useEffect, they immediately got reset back to what they are supposed to be.

In the parent component, I set the key to `filter_obj.length`

```
<Archive key = {filter_obj.length} state={state_filter}/>
```

which should destroy all previous states when filter_obj length changes, but itemData still got reset back as shown by their length here
[image]

Here's my code for reference. I'm using react-infinite-scroll-component.

```
export default function Archive(props) {
    const [width, height] = useWindowSize()
    const [manifest, setManifest]= useState({});
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [apiUrl,setapiurl] = useState([])
    const [itemData, setData] = useState([])
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)
    const {filter_obj, set_filter_obj} = props.state;

    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(16);
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

    const handleOpen = (manifest) => {
      setOpen(true);
      setManifest(manifest)}
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    const modalStyle = {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        p: 4,
        maxHeight: 500,
      };


      const fetchData = async () => {
      var data = new FormData();

        data.append("hierarchical", "False");
        
        data.append("selected_fields", 'url');
        data.append("results_per_page", rowsPerPage);
        data.append("results_page", page + 1);
         for (const property in filter_obj) {
          filter_obj[property].forEach((v) => {
            data.append(property, v);
          })}
       
        const res = await fetch('url',{
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
          headers: {'Authorization':AUTH_TOKEN}
        })
        const result = await res.json();
        setapiurl(result)
        const fetchImage = async ()=> {
          const promises = result.map(uri => {
            return fetch(Object.values(uri), {
              method: "GET",
            }).then(res => {
              return res.json()
            }).then(res => {
              var dict = {"title": res.label.none[0], "image": curImage(res.thumbnail[0].id),"uri":uri}
              return dict;
            })
          })
          const response = await Promise.all(promises)
          setData([...itemData, ...response])
          
          if(response.length<=0){
            
            setHasMore(false)
          }
        
        }
        fetchImage().catch(console.error);
      }

      useEffect(()=>{
        setPage(0);
        setData([])
        setapiurl( [])   
        fetchData()
          
        
      }, [filter_obj])




    return (
      <div id="infinite-container" style={{ overflow: 'auto'}}>
      <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={itemData.length} //This is important field to render the next data
      next={fetchData}
      getScrollParent={()=>document.getElementById('infinite-container')} 
      useWindow={false}

      hasMore={hasMore}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
      endMessage={
        <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          end message
        </p>
      } >


     <ImageList sx={{ width: width, height: "99%" }} cols={
              Math.sqrt(rowsPerPage)
              } gap={30} >
     
              {itemData.map((item) => (
                <ImageListItem key={item.image}>
                  <img
                    src={`${item.image}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
                    srcSet={`${item.image}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
                    alt={item.title}
                    loading="lazy"
                  />
                  <ImageListItemBar
                    title={item.title}
                    sx ={{
                      bgcolor: alpha('#549165',0.8)
                    }}
                    actionIcon={
                      <IconButton
                        sx={{ color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)' }}
                        aria-label={`info about ${item.title}`}
                        onClick={() => handleOpen(item.uri.url)}
                      >
                        <InfoIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    }
                  />
                </ImageListItem>
              ))}
              
            </ImageList>
    
        </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I feel changing the key wont help, since it will rest the components state
but in the code, the filterObj is passed from the parent so you can try to reset the state in parent and you might not need the key since the component will rerender on every filter state change

Comment: After moving the following to the parent component, 

`const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);`
`const [apiUrl,setapiurl] = useState([])`
`const [itemData, setData] = useState([])`,


`itemData` was reset to [] but immediately came back with old result + new result (say originally the console logged it has 20 entries, the entries was cleared to 0 when `filterObj ` updates but right after console logged it has 21 entries again).